# Why does a yacc-generated state machine state not include a valid next token?

Tags: parsing, yacc, ply

I'm using PLY (Python Lex/Yacc) for a parser.  I'm getting the following output:

```
State  : 52
Stack  : <shortened preamble> primary_expr ARROW simple_name LPAREN ID COLON . LexToken(INTEGER,'Integer',13,362)
Action : Shift and goto state 116

State  : 116
Stack  : <shortened preamble> primary_expr ARROW simple_name LPAREN ID COLON INTEGER . LexToken(BAR,'|',13,370)
ERROR: Error  : <shortened preamble> primary_expr ARROW simple_name LPAREN ID COLON INTEGER . LexToken(BAR,'|',13,370)
```

You can see that in state 52, it shifted the `INTEGER` token, and went to state 116.  The state machine output file for state 116 has this:

```
state 116

  (56) simple_type -> INTEGER .

  RBRACKET        reduce using rule 56 (simple_type -> INTEGER .)
  EQ              reduce using rule 56 (simple_type -> INTEGER .)
  SEMI            reduce using rule 56 (simple_type -> INTEGER .)
```

This seems to be a state just to reduce `INTEGER` to `simple_type`.  Yet the `BAR` token (which appears next in the input) is not listed here.

The rule I *expect* to be matched is:

```
iterator_expr : primary_expr ARROW simple_name LPAREN uninitialized_variable BAR other_expr RPAREN
```

These other rules provide the reduction of the last three tokens to match the rule.

```
simple_type : INTEGER
type_specifier : simple_type
declarator : ID COLON type_specifier
uninitialized_variable : declarator
```

*So*, it looks to me like the state machine is all set to go into state 116, reduce `INTEGER` to `simple_type`, `simple_type` to `type_specifier`, `ID COLON type_specifier` to `declarator`, `declarator` to `uninitialized_variable`, and continue happily with `BAR` from there.  However, it seems to be going to a state with only shift actions and complaining about the next shift.  There are no shift/reduce or reduce/reduce conflicts about any of the rules mentioned.

Why would it *need* to consider `BAR` next, and why didn't it list it as a possibility in the state machine?

EDIT 4/20/18:
I changed the rule I expect to be matched to:

```
iterator_expr : primary_expr ARROW simple_name LPAREN declarator BAR other_expr RPAREN
```

(i.e., changed `uninitialized_variable` to `declarator`), and `BAR` now appears as a next token in state 116.  The parser now chooses to reducue `simple_type -> INTEGER` rather than shift `BAR`, and matches fine.  I wonder if there's something about having to match a non-terminals (`unintialized_variable`), then matching some terminals (ID, COLON) and some non-terminals that somehow thwarts detection of valid next tokens.

I realized no one can debug this without the full grammar (which is unfortunately proprietary).  But I'm interested to understand what principles of yacc might be involved, and also looking to document good debugging techniques for these weird issues.  I'm actually encountering this issue for other rules that include an `expression` non-terminal inside of other rules--things like '+' show up as invalid next token, when clearly the `expression` non-terminal should cover it.  How *does* the list of next valid tokens get created, and what would prevent one so clearly listed in a rule from showing up?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without seeing the complete grammar. Also, it seems odd to me that state 116 does not have a default action. Are you quotimg the entire state description?

Comment: @rici  Yes, that's the entire state description.  Unfortunately, the grammar is proprietary, so I can't post it all, and I understand that _really_ limits my chances here.  But I'd settle for suggestions of things to look at or hunches if you happen to have seen something like this before.

Comment: What you wonder about in your edit is almost definitely not happening. What might be happening is that uninitialized_value has some unshown alternative which allows a BAR to be shifted, creating a shift-reduce conflict which is resolved in favour of the shift. You don't report any conflict warnings and it would be extremely bad form to hide them from us, but that is still consistent with a precedence declaration. I hope you understand my reluctance to speculate further. You could try to make a [mcve]; if not, I'll VTC as unanswerable since you say you cannot provide more details.

Comment: A minimal example is a good idea, though I suspect if I can approach that, I'm likely to solve my problems and this question will never be updated.  I think there is value is having answers like, "you can visualize the sequence of rules applied by..." or "The state machine is formed by XYZ.  You can control that by doing ABC to see which decisions are taking precedence."  This is an area where debugging is considered something of a black art, and I'm trying to get the community to provide more advanced help for debugging grammars larger than the trivial examples you find today.

Comment: For instance, I followed your suggestion about conflict on BAR and diff'ed the parser.out before and after the change.  There were no conflicts related to BAR, the non-terminals directly involved, or the rules involved.  I could ask, "How do you visualize/debug large grammars with no clearly related conflicts," but I'm almost certain that would be voted too vague.

Comment: Rules are not applied in any sequence, so your visualisation must start by discarding that idea. In effect, all applicable rules are available and if there is more than one and one is a reduce, then you have a conflict. Your other starting phrase is similarly inapplicable. As for "how do you visualise large grammars?", I think my only answer is "with a certain amount of difficulty". Consequently, if you cannot figure out the conflict by tracing backwards through the state machine, your best bet is precisely to start with a smaller grammar and add features one at a time until...

Comment: ...you find a conflict. If you do that, instead of us, then whether or not this question gets answered drpends on your generosity. But if you cannot share the grammar, that's basically what you're left with.

Comment: As far as my suggestion about BAR goes, I'm not sure how you interpreted it but my mom intention was to suggest that precedence declarations (if you have them) could be hiding a conflict. I'd start by getting rid of them (if you have them) which will require rewriting parts of your grammar (although the rewrite is usually very straight forward). But. I really dislike trying to provide information based on hypotheticals.

Comment: Thanks, @rici.  I _do_ appreciate your help.  I'm making progress, and would like to capture the kind of suggestions I was hoping to find.  I'd ask to leave this question open so I have a place to capture those lessons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your parser errors out, it's because there's a syntax error--it doesn't have a valid option to shift *or* reduce, so it's concluded that your input doesn't match the grammar.  If you're convinced otherwise, a few observations may help in figuring out why the two of you have come to different conclusions.

1. Remember that LALR parsers generate one deterministic state machine for parsing the input.  Whatever state it's in, given a next token, it will make exactly one decision and move on.  Your grammar must be formed in such a way that, for any valid input, there is always a single valid next action for the state machine.
2. A syntax error is a dead end, but that doesn't mean that only the last turn you took was the wrong one.  Shift/Reduce and Reduce/Reduce conflicts may have been present in previously applied rules, and were resolved in some way.  That way probably set you on a course for the rest of your input not to match a valid next action.

It's very likely that you have an ambiguity earlier on in your parse tree, and the method the parser chose to resolve that ambiguity is making the rest of your particular input turn out to not be acceptable.  You need to examine the parsing history to find the point at which that happened, understand what it is about your grammar that seems to want two or more choices to be simultaneously valid, and re-write the rules of the grammar to prevent that.  Good tips for finding this point in the history:

1. Reconstruct the state history and rule application for your input string.  Then go through your parser.out file to find any conflicts for any of those rules.  See if that conflict could affect the parsing of the input string.
2. Create a simple example around the part of your grammar that seems to be involved.  Feed that simple grammar to tools like [JFLAP](http://www.jflap.org) or [JsMachines](http://jsmachines.sourceforge.net/machines/lalr1.html).  Have the tool parse a representative input and see what decision it's making at each step. Remember in these tools that 's#' means "shift and go to state #", and 'r#' means "reduce according to rule #", and just '#' means "go to state #."  You'll see the states that get returned too after reductions on the stack, which will help understand in which rules the parser thinks it might be completing.

It might be very nice for some tool like PLY to generate a state machine that, on conflict, puts the parse through a state which logs that this was the point at which a conflict was found, then automatically proceeds to the state chosen for resolution.  You might be able to add that into PLY's yacc module.

If you need your grammar to deal with a few possibilities until the syntax resolves them to a single option, you can probably add non-terminal rules that it can track.  You're effectively trying to force the state machine to choose "shift" for some amount of tokens until the resolving syntax is encountered.  Then the application of reductions should be unique.  To get it to choose "shift," there must be multiple applicable productions that represent possible choices, but to make the reductions unique, they must end in some unique way.  You may be able to cover the grammar elements from the point of ambiguity until the resolution with a small number of non-terminal productions and get the optionality you need.